# When does the thread that calls Lock.lock() returns from the call, when the the lock is not available immediately?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

**From Documentation:**

The documentation for  `Condition.signalAll()` says,

'Wakes up all waiting threads.
If any threads are waiting on this condition then they are all woken up. Each thread must re-acquire the lock before it can return from await. '

The threads that are waiting as mentioned above includes the threads that have called some overloaded variation of

`Condition.await(...)`,

whose documentation says 'The lock associated with this condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until ...'

**The case for discussion:**
So lets say a thread has become disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lying dormant after calling `Condition.await(...)` and wakes up later as another thread has called `Condition.signalAll()` and the competes with other thread to re-acquire the lock before returning the wait.

*So, I take, the thread has to wake up from its disabled state for (thread scheduling purposes) and compete before acquiring the lock.*

**The question in title:**

The documentation for `Lock.lock()` says,

'If the lock is not available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired.'

*Now, what about a thread that has become disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lying dormant, since the lock was not available at the instant it has called `lock()` method?*

*When will such a thread wake up from its disables state and compete, so that it can acquire the lock?*

**Note:**

*1. All the `Condition` objects mentions refer to a singular Condition object obtained from the same `Lock` object in discussion.*

*2. This scenario doesn't arise in implicit locks as all threads that call synchronized code just block each other and compete for lock without disabling themselves.*

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. It says _lies dormant until the lock has been acquired_.

Comment: it says until the lock has been acquired by the current thread. See documentation for `lockInterruptibly()`, since `lock()`is same as `lockInterruptibly()` just that `lock()` method doesn't throw exception.

I just don't a scenario when the current thread acquires the Lock, since it never wakes up

Comment: Acquiring the lock makes it wake up.

Comment: Or are you asking how the acquisition works?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thats why I have mentioned, how I came to infer that "the thread has to wake up from its disabled state for (thread scheduling purposes) first before competing to acquiring the lock.", in the 'The case for discussion:' section, which if its true will negate the argument "Acquiring the lock makes the thread wake up". As a thread has to wake up first to acquire the lock

Comment: Which `Lock` implementation are you interested in?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not  specifically talking about any particular `Lock` implementation as I have mentioned the documentation of generalized `Lock` interface only.

Comment: The `Lock` documentation doesn't say how because that's an implementation detail. Each implementation may do it differently.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am confused. How can an argument made only by quoting documentation of interface refute with the working of a specific implementation of the same interface?

Are you saying either 'Acquiring the lock makes a thread wake up' or 'the thread has to wake up from its disabled state for (thread scheduling purposes) first before competing to acquiring the lock' depends on the implementation?

Comment: You're getting stuck on the English. When the thread wakes up, it is considered as having _acquired the lock_. The acquisition technique is an implementation detail.

Comment: Ok, just a question 'Are the threads that are disabled via `Condition.await(...)` and `Lock.lock()`' in different states? or is this implementation dependent?

Comment: I finally understood that each implementation makes sense and the question I asked is part of implementation detail.

Comment: You might enjoy looking at the source code of `ReentrantLock` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I take, the thread has to wake up from its disabled state for (thread scheduling purposes) and compete before acquiring the lock.

Correct. Some systems pre-assign the lock to the thread before re-enabling it for scheduling as part of the "release the lock" process. But the more typical design is simply to reschedule the thread and let it compete for the lock.

> Now, what about a thread that has become disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lying dormant, since the lock was not available at the instant it has called lock() method?
>
> When will such a thread wake up from its disables state and compete, so that it can acquire the lock?

Typically, as soon as the thread that holds the lock releases it. The typical implementation is that the thread adds itself to a list of threads waiting for the lock before disabling itself. When the lock is released, that list is checked by the thread releasing the lock and at least one thread on the list is re-enabled.

Comment: So, are you saying the list of threads that waits for the lock has threads that are active (i.e. threads that got woke up by `Condition.signalAll()`) and also threads that are disabled by `Lock.lock()`. 

But such a list should not contain the the threads that are disabled via another condition's `await(...)` method since those threads such not acquire the lock unless notified, isn't it?

Comment: That is one possible implementation, yes. The threads that are waiting to compete for the lock that are disabled are on a list. That list is checked when a thread releases the lock.

Comment: I finally understood that each implementation makes sense and the question I asked is part of implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

The thread is disabled for scheduling purposes, meaning it won't get CPU time, but it's still waiting to acquire the lock. So instead of being in `RUNNABLE` state, it's in `WAITING` state.

When the lock is released the thread has a chance of acquiring it or staying in `WAITING`, and the process repeats. `Condition` doesn't seem to be relevant to this question in any way.